# "Why, when, how and where" are not interrogative pronouns. Why?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, grammar, grammaticality, expressions

I have the following question:

> **What**, **who**, **which**, **whom** and **whose** are interrogative pronouns, but ***why***, ***when***, ***how*** and ***where*** are not. Why?

Please answer this question briefly. Thank you.

Comment: Very briefly, words like "when" can be an adverb, conjunction, pronoun, and noun. "I will move my car when ready." (adverb), "Please move you car when you are asked to do so." (conjunction), "I need to move the car by when?" (pronoun), and in rarer form, "What does the 'when' mean in your notice, about moving the car when it's necessary?" (noun).

Comment: @Cargill: It seems pointless to mention the last case. By the same definition, any word can be a noun. It seems better to me to retain a use-mention distinction and to not consider this a use of the word *when*.

Comment: @Cargill The word *when* is a preposition in all uses  - apart from when merely cited.

Comment: Understand that the tag "interrogative" is fairly arbitrarily defined and is just intended as a rough guide to help determine if an English sentence is a question or not.

Comment: I disagree that 'when' is a preposition in all cases ... at least it is such a generalised term that you might just as well say "when is a time-related joining word in all cases".

Comment: @sumelic: I take your point, but "when" does have a specific use as a noun that many other non-noun words do not have, so I think it is not unreasonable to include the noun use, other than just when it's being cited.

Comment: @Cargill: But, can't any word be used as a noun in that way? Taking your example sentence, we can say "the" is a noun: "What does the 'the' mean in your notice, about moving the car when it's necessary?" Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this a "do my homework" question?

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down.

**What**, **who**, **which**, **whom**, and **whose** can be persons, places, or things.  That's what makes them [pronouns](https://www.google.com/search?q=pronouns&oq=pronouns&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60l2&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

They convey the force of a question.  That's what makes them [interrogative](https://www.google.com/search?q=interrogative&oq=interrogative&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60l2&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

As for **why**, **when**, and **how**, these convey a question but are not persons, places, or things.

That leaves **where**, which is certainly a question and certainly seems like a place and thus a pronoun.  Yet is not on any list of interrogative pronouns I can find.

Well it turns out that **where** is almost, but not quiet, a place and thus almost but not quite a pronoun.  Instead it is an adverb.

Here's why:

> I am going [to school] → I am going [where] → [Where] are you going?

Where didn't take the place of school like a pronoun.  It took the place of the prepositional phrase: **to school**

Almost, but not quite, a pronoun.

Instead, you may, if you like, consider **where** an [interrogative pro-adverb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10480/why-is-where-an-adverb-and-not-a-pronoun)

Comment: *Where* is a preposition.

Answer (score 2):

***What, who, whom***, ***whose:***

We consider these words pronouns because like other pronouns they can do jobs typically done by noun phrases in a phrase or clause:

- **An accident** happened / **It** happened / **What** happened?
- We are watching **that acrobat** / We are watching **her** / **Whom** are we watching?
- **A woman** arrived / **She** arrived / **Who** arrived?
- **The elephant's** mother arrived /  **His** mother arrived / **Whose** mother arrived?

These interrogative pronouns share the syntactic properties of other pronouns.

***How, why, when***, ***where:***

These words do other types of jobs in clauses and phrases. For example they can all represent different types of Adjunct (Adverbial) in a clause:

- He's travelling **by bus** / **How** is he travelling?
- He's travelling **because he needs to go to a meeting** / **Why** is he travelling?
- He's travelling **on Monday** / **When** is he travelling?
- He's travelling **in France** / **Where** is he travelling?

We see these words functioning as Adjuncts of instrument, cause, time and place respectively in the sentences above.  Interrogative *how* and *why* are usually adverbs. They share many of the properties of other adverbs. Interrogative *when* and *where* are prepositions.

Comment: Do you have a citation? If "where" is a preposition, then is "how" also a preposition in the example sentence you gave?

Comment: @sumelic No, it isn't. You posted while I was editing! *Where* shares the syntactic properties of other prepositions (modifiable by *right*, post-modifier of nouns, freely occurs as a Predicative Complement. *How* - which can be a troublesome beast, shares the syntactic properties of adverbs. For example, won't freely occur as a PC, can't post-modify nouns, not modifiable by *right*.

Comment: @sumelic You could try Oxford Modern English Grammar, Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, A students Introduction to English Grammar. Don't have the page numbers, though.

Comment: I can see how that applies to "where" when it is used as a relative... preposition ("I found the book right **where** I left it" and "It was right **where** I left it" seem analogous to "I found the book right **on** the bookshelf" and "It was right **on** the bookshelf.") "How" also seems to be able to be used predicatively  ("It's just **how** I left it."), so maybe this isn't what you mean? But when *where* is used as an interrogative, we can't say "**Right** where is he traveling?" And I don't see how interrogative *where* could post-modify nouns either.

Comment: @sumelic See [this page (168) on interrogatives from MEG](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7ryuRtiasPYC&pg=PA168&dq=recall+that+when+and+where+%22oxford+modern+english+grammar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwkf2NjrrJAhXLCBoKHQ_QAhQQ6AEILjAA#v=onepage&q=recall%20that%20when%20and%20where%20%22oxford%20modern%20english%20grammar%22&f=false). So re the syntax: *I know right where you are*.  A: "People at home blah blah" B: "People where?" So the first is interrogative *where* modified by *right*. The second is interrogative *where* postmodifying *people* ...

Comment: "I know right where you are" is not interrogative *where*. That second example is helpful though, thanks.

Comment: @sumelic Your *how* is the adjective *how*, not the adverb *how*. [I did warn you that *how* was troublesome*]. In your sentence it's a PC, not a modifier in an NP. Note the strategically placed *usually* in my post when describing *how* as an adverb!

Comment: @sumelic Probably not. Let's try "Right here", "Right where?". That any good?

Comment: Yes, that seems to work.

Comment: What about cases like Cargill's example where the preposition is included, such as "I need to move the car by *when*?" or "We should go to *where*?" or "Where does he come from?" Here it seems to be a pronoun.

Comment: @sumelic Well, I'll cut it short, but prepositions take preposition phrase complements, just like verbs take verb phrase complements. So in, "*He came back out from under behind where he had been hiding*" none of the prepositions are nouns any more than the verbs are nouns in "*He wanted to try to learn to aspire to want to teach Spanish*".